# How to sort by child entities that matches the condition in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entities in Spring Boot. It's a `Record` which can be "described" by any `RecordProperty`

```
@Entity
public class Record {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean active = false;
    
    private RecordType type;
    
    private String title;

    @OneToMany
    private List<RecordProperty> properties;
    
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class RecordProperty {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String propertyName;

    private String value;
}
```

I get them like below:

```
Page<Record> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Here is an example list of such objects that I get using `JPA`'s `Pageable`

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "active": true,
            "type": "Manual",
            "title": "Some title",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "propertyName": "Foo",
                    "value": "121"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "propertyName": "Bar",
                    "value": "1122"
                }
            ],

        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "active": true,
            "type": "Auto",
            "title": "Some another title",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "propertyName": "Foo",
                    "value": "999"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "propertyName": "Bar",
                    "value": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "numberOfItems": 2,
    "numberOfPages": 1
}
```

List of the records is displayed in the table on the frontend. Additionally, all properties are converted to the columns. So `property.propertyName` becomes a column, and `property.value` becomes a cell. Like below:

| id | active | type | title | Foo | Bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | Manual | Some title | 121 | 1122 |
| 2 | true | Auto | Some another title | 999 | 0 |

When I use `Sort` of `Pageable` on `id`, `active`, `type` or `title` columns, it obviously works. But how can I sort by the properties values which can be dynamic and different every time? I would need to first filter the records matching propertyName (for example `Foo`) and then sort by `Foo`'s value. But how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of relational properties like this:

```
@OrderBy("value")
@OneToMany
private List<RecordProperty> properties;
```

That will sort the values WITHIN a single `properties`. If you want to sort across ALL `properties` then you'd need to do that after you have the list.

Comment: Above approach will not include matching by propertyName. I want to sort ALL of the Records by value, where propertyName i equal to given String.